# sorting not working as expected in ibm bluemix node red environment

Tags: couchdb, ibm-cloud, cloudant, node-red

I have created index using [this post request](https://c49ecf98817cace84679b2a18aa038e5a10a83725f05690d04c5e54086c3913d@ea862f09-ac8d-48a8-b5b5-afea0ac0f880-bluemix.cloudant.com/pollution_aqi_db/_index)
payload :

```
{
  "index": {
    "fields": [

        "sortdate","coordinates"
            ]
      },
    "type": "json"
  }
```

and index created successfully.
Now i fetch the record using [this post request 
URL](https://ea862f09-ac8d-48a8-b5b5-afea0ac0f880-bluemix.cloudant.com/pollution_aqi_db/_find)

Payload:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "coordinates": [18.497484,73.81349]
  },
   "sort": [
    {
      "sortdate": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```

and getting following response:

```
{
    "warning": "no matching index found, create an index to optimize query time",
    "docs": [
        {
            "_id": "4254f2d4638806b54802144ff25ecba7",
            "_rev": "1-6d3d573f21eb6d6518093aeb36a3ed5f",
            "aqi": 26,
            "coordinates": [
                18.497484,
                73.81349
            ],
            "so2": {
                "avg": 10,
                "aqi": 12
            },
            "pm10": {
                "avg": 26,
                "aqi": 26
            },
            "pm25": {
                "avg": 13,
                "aqi": 21
            },
            "date": "2017-06-30T11:08:45.439Z",
            "sortdate": 1498820925439
        },
        {
            "_id": "7c0278d8dfb3182c54ee1d6b03839b74",
            "_rev": "1-09d2b1354177f306b859f7f8c33d65d1",
            "aqi": 25,
            "coordinates": [
                18.497484,
                73.81349
            ],
            "so2": {
                "avg": 9,
                "aqi": 11
            },
            "pm10": {
                "avg": 25,
                "aqi": 25
            },
            "pm25": {
                "avg": 14,
                "aqi": 23
            },
            "date": "2017-06-30T09:56:55.004Z",
            "sortdate": 1498816615004
        },
        {
            "_id": "98e28cd2012a7c1b922f944162d12e00",
            "_rev": "1-b62d7c5fee4c9c9699cb7a9f950ec62c",
            "aqi": 25,
            "coordinates": [
                18.497484,
                73.81349
            ],
            "so2": {
                "avg": 9,
                "aqi": 11
            },
            "pm10": {
                "avg": 25,
                "aqi": 25
            },
            "pm25": {
                "avg": 14,
                "aqi": 23
            },
            "date": "2017-06-30T10:23:22.896Z",
            "sortdate": 1498818202896
        },
        {
            "_id": "cb6f3d1a313df7e95326d13085b480c9",
            "_rev": "1-77678d8df1c04dfc33f513906a97ca1e",
            "aqi": 26,
            "coordinates": [
                18.497484,
                73.81349
            ],
            "so2": {
                "avg": 10,
                "aqi": 12
            },
            "pm10": {
                "avg": 26,
                "aqi": 26
            },
            "pm25": {
                "avg": 13,
                "aqi": 21
            },
            "date": "2017-06-30T11:08:05.364Z",
            "sortdate": 1498820885364
        },
        {
            "_id": "db1fe2e2403f8acd8655a3a65cf4b36c",
            "_rev": "1-ef51370ef1ddc7215512b4644d095634",
            "aqi": 25,
            "coordinates": [
                18.497484,
                73.81349
            ],
            "so2": {
                "avg": 9,
                "aqi": 11
            },
            "pm10": {
                "avg": 25,
                "aqi": 25
            },
            "pm25": {
                "avg": 14,
                "aqi": 23
            },
            "date": "2017-06-30T09:42:40.284Z",
            "sortdate": 1498815760284
        },
        {
            "_id": "e226e828bce5e31534db87f44f98efae",
            "_rev": "1-2a238373a47575158866c56019d75fbe",
            "aqi": 25,
            "coordinates": [
                18.497484,
                73.81349
            ],
            "so2": {
                "avg": 9,
                "aqi": 11
            },
            "pm10": {
                "avg": 25,
                "aqi": 25
            },
            "pm25": {
                "avg": 14,
                "aqi": 23
            },
            "date": "2017-06-30T09:43:18.894Z",
            "sortdate": 1498815798894
        },
        {
            "_id": "e38663621c6148952fd84e3ab54195c0",
            "_rev": "1-fa45393376d7dc8677ebd48bd2804d70",
            "aqi": 26,
            "coordinates": [
                18.497484,
                73.81349
            ],
            "so2": {
                "avg": 10,
                "aqi": 12
            },
            "pm10": {
                "avg": 26,
                "aqi": 26
            },
            "pm25": {
                "avg": 14,
                "aqi": 23
            },
            "date": "2017-06-30T10:25:17.277Z",
            "sortdate": 1498818317277
        },
        {
            "_id": "e435e43de6bcb01c1596874afacef581",
            "_rev": "1-072be28b4128118e443c500494f456a1",
            "aqi": 26,
            "coordinates": [
                18.497484,
                73.81349
            ],
            "so2": {
                "avg": 10,
                "aqi": 12
            },
            "pm10": {
                "avg": 26,
                "aqi": 26
            },
            "pm25": {
                "avg": 13,
                "aqi": 21
            },
            "date": "2017-06-30T11:59:21.235Z",
            "sortdate": 1498823961235
        },
        {
            "_id": "f195832354b6fc816e1039dacf41546f",
            "_rev": "1-52fa322d3c034ddf70259991ac7c7021",
            "aqi": 26,
            "coordinates": [
                18.497484,
                73.81349
            ],
            "so2": {
                "avg": 10,
                "aqi": 12
            },
            "pm10": {
                "avg": 26,
                "aqi": 26
            },
            "pm25": {
                "avg": 14,
                "aqi": 23
            },
            "date": "2017-06-30T10:24:01.539Z",
            "sortdate": 1498818241539
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see  record are not coming sorted as per sortdate field.

I am not getting what is wrong here.

Comment: Please provide some context, like which node you are trying to use.

Comment: It appears that your index is not being used for your query: `"no matching index found, create an index to optimize query time"`

Comment: @chughts : I used first request to create index, and it was successful. Do you have any pointer how I debug this more.

Comment: @ChrisSnow : I used http node for sending http request and function node to modify or add header parameter. Http response node to send response back to client.

Comment: @Anil, have you seen the tutorials here: https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/cloudant-query-new/

Answer (score 1):

When you instruct Cloudant to create an index from the fields "sortdate","coordinates", it creates an data structure on disk ordered by `sortdate` and `coordinates`. If you subsequently perform a query that can be optimised using this index then your query will be get a performance boost.

Unfortunately, the query you are making is not helped by the index you created. Querying by `coordinates` on its own is helped by an index on sortdate & coordinates.

Your query may be boosted by an index on `coordinates` on its own e.g.

```
{
  "index": {
    "fields": [

        "sortdate","coordinates"
            ]
      },
    "type": "json"
}
```